# Dropdown list mvc5 from other model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

First time using MVC to develop an app and have run into an issues populating a dropdown in the student create view with a list of teachers.

I have 2 models

```
public class Student
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Parent/Guardian Name")]
    public string ParentGuardianName { get; set; }

    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }


    public MembershipOption MembershipOption { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Progress> Progress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Report> Report { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Signed Up Date")]
    public DateTime? SignedUpDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }



}

 public class Teacher
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

}

I have the create view of the student model that looks like this

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentGuardianName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Teacher, // 1. Store selected value in Model.State;
                                         // when page is rendered after postback,
                                         // take selected value from Model.State.

                                       // 2. Take list of values from Model.States
                                       Model.Teacher,

                                       // 3. Text for the first 'default' option
                                       "- Please select a Teacher -",

                                       //4. A class name to assign to <select> tag
                                       new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Teacher, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The dropdownlist for Teachers throws an exception due to Teacher being null.

How do i go about adding the teachers drop down list to this student create cshtml?

Im assuming i need to get the teachers when the student model is called, but not sure where it needs to be put in the studentscontroller?

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object (which is what `Teacher` is) - a `<select>` binds to a posts back a single simple value. Suggest your look at the code in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) to understand how to generate a dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter should be a list of SelectListItem's so that the helper method can use that list to generate the SELECT options. But you are trying to pass the `Teacher` navigational property instead of that!

You should create a view model for your view, which has properties to accept the form input values. Since you want to add a dropdown to the view, add 2 properties to the view model. one for the selected value and one for the list of items we need to use to render the dropdown

```
public class CreateStudent
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } 

    // to do : Add other properties AS NEEDED BY THE VIEW
    // Do not just copy all the properties from Entity class

    public List<SelectListItem> Teachers { set; get; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Select Teacher")]
    public int SelectedTeacherId { set; get; }
}
```

Now in your GET action, you need to create an object of this view model, populate the `Teachers` collection property and send the object to the view

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new CreateStudent();
    vm.Teachers = GetTeachers();
    return View(vm);
}

private List<SelectListItem> GetTeachers()
{
    return db.Teachers.Select(a => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = a.Id.ToString(),
        Text = a.Name
    }).ToList();
}
```

Now in your view, which is strongly typed to our view model, we can use DropDownListFor helper method to render the SELECT element

```
@model CreateStudent
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.FirstName)

    @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.LastName)

    @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.SelectedTeacherId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.SelectedTeacherId , Model.Teachers, "select one")

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action, use the same view model as your action method parameter, and read the values from it's properties and use that to create a new object of your entity class and save it

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateStudent model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  { 
     var s = new Student { FirstName=model.FirstName };
     s.LastName = model.LastName;
     // to do : Map other property values as well from view model
     db.Students.Add(s);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  //Make sure to RELOAD the Teachers list for dropdown
  model.Teachers = GetTeachers();
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Just to add, how do i set the selected index on this dropdown list?

Comment: in the GET action, set the `SelectedTeacherId` to one of the `TeacherId` values and the helper will make the option selected.